# Upload build from itune's testflight for iOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded the build to testflight and testing ok but I would like to release testflight build to public use (Public release), Will I have to upload the build again with different build number or I can upload the app from testflight section?

Comment: public release means release to the appStore?

Comment: Testflight is the beta testing. You have to upload build as regularly you do and after that add your build in testflight.

Comment: I mean i have already uploaded the build to testflight. Now I want to testflight build to appStore, can i have any option within testflight for releasing appstore?

Comment: @abcdgef yes you can release your testflight build but make sure you uploaded it with production certificate not adhock 
after creating the new version your build automatically show of in build section but make sure you create same version which is in build.

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman, Yes

Comment: @abcd-gef : You would upload your ipa to itunesConnect even if you want to make it available in testFlight. So obviously there is no need to upload two different builds one for TestFlight and one for App Store. You can go ahead and submit your current TestFlight build to review. Once review is completed app will be made public. Additional piece of info: TestFlights are intended for making build available for testing so your current testFlight build might have urls pointing to testServers which u might wanna change while making build for production in that case u need to upload new build

Comment: @abcd-gef : So every single build you upload to itunesConnect becomes available to TestFlight and you can submit any of the build you uploaded (belonging to current version) to itunesConnect to review.

Comment: @chiragshah, How can I release the testflight build to appStore? I can not find any option (Button) ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, I does not understand bellow point, Additional piece of info: TestFlights are intended for making build available for testing so your current testFlight build might have urls pointing to testServers which u might wanna change while making build for production in that case u need to upload new build

Comment: @abcd-gef : If your app is not a standalone app and involves server communication and u happened to have production and development environments (different servers or different instances of backend app in sever) then u might have given a build to your testers earlier with url pointing to test environment releasing the same build to production will be a disaster hence in such cases you might have to make a new build with updated url end points.

Comment: I confuse, let me clear myself... app is on testflight, all tester passed the app and now ready to release for appstore, In itunes  I can see bellow          Build    Ituneconnect users         External Tester .....                                               1.0.1            Testing                     Ready to submit                                                     now, I click on 1.0.1 but I can not find any option to release that build to appstore, I can only see button "Expire build"

Comment: @abcdgef your build that upload to test flight that is ok then you no need to upload new build to test flight just use that build to upload app store you just need to select version if your version is uploaded previously then you need to upload new app with increased version and build number if your version is first or no have same version then no need to upload new build or version..

Comment: @abcdgefjust login to itunesconnect.apple.com and goto app store> if no version and plate form then add or if exiting then fill information and upload screen shot in bellow just select build that is latest and general information in add version number. after all information fill submit for review that take 1 or 2 day in processing.